# C++ mostly redundant default and parameterized constructors violating DRY

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor, parameterized

(using C++ in Visual Studio)

I have the following default constructor used to create a spaceship object:

```
Ship() // default constructor
{
    name = "[ship unnamed]";
    length = 1000;
    width = 500;
    power = 100;

    vector<int> temp = { 100, 100 }; // { current health, maximum health}

    bridge = temp;
    sensor_arrays.push_back(temp); // 2 sensor arrays
    sensor_arrays.push_back(temp);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) // create 12 each
    {
        lasers.push_back(temp);
        heavy_lasers.push_back(temp);
        strike_fighters.push_back(temp);
        strike_bombers.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

Then I have the following parameterized constructor used to create a ship given a name:

```
Ship(string custom_name)
{
    name = custom_name;
    length = 1000;
    width = 500;
    power = 100;

    vector<int> temp = { 100, 100 }; // { current health, maximum health}

    bridge = temp;
    sensor_arrays.push_back(temp); // 2 sensor arrays
    sensor_arrays.push_back(temp);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) // create 12 each
    {
        lasers.push_back(temp);
        heavy_lasers.push_back(temp);
        strike_fighters.push_back(temp);
        strike_bombers.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

Only one single line changed, so this appears to violate DRY.

I could just use the default constructor then manually change what I need, but I'd like to have one or more parameterized constructors without repeating the same lines of code. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: First, delegating constructors. Second, this can all be done with a constructor initializer list.

Comment: another way would be to use a default value for custom_name

Comment: if your compiler does not support delegating constructors you can create an artificial base class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Chris' answer, I implemented an initializer list as described [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html).

Solution: (original code in question)

```
Ship(string custom_name) : Ship()
{
    name = custom_name;
    /*length = 1000;
    width = 500;
    power = 100;

    vector<int> temp = { 100, 100 };

    bridge = temp;
    sensor_arrays.push_back(temp); // 2 sensor arrays
    sensor_arrays.push_back(temp);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) // create 12 each
    {
        lasers.push_back(temp);
        heavy_lasers.push_back(temp);
        strike_fighters.push_back(temp);
        strike_bombers.push_back(temp);
    }*/
}
```

Comment: A better solutions would to implement the default constructor using the other constructor. `Ship() : Ship("[ship unnamed]") {}`. This way, `name` is initialized correctly to start with and there is no need for an assignment.

Answer (score 3):

You may use one of the following:

```
explicit Ship(const std::string& custom_name = "[ship unnamed]") {/*your code*/}
```

or

```
Ship() : Ship("[ship unnamed]") {} // delegate constructor, require C++11
explicit Ship(const std::string& custom_name) {/*your code*/}
```